# Container padding not set when changing screen size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using a media breakpoint to remove the container's padding on smaller screens:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .content-wrapper > .content {
        padding: 0 0;
    }

    .container, .container-fluid, .container-xl, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm {
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}
```

[image: Container]

[image: Styles]

However, this is not working. The padding doesn't change. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this get embedded before or after the Bootstrap styles? I am guessing that most likely you have an issue with order, and/or specificity. Inspecting the element(s) in question using your browser dev tools should be able to give you clarity on what styles get applied, and which ones might get overwritten.

Comment: My styles are embedded after Bootstrap. The styles are not being overwritten.

Comment: Looks lither you are not within the breakpoint boundaries here, or your addition never made it into the stylesheet(s) in the first place. You should at least _see_ your own rules there, even if the values got overwritten by something else.

Comment: You need to give us a bit more context. Where is that line 539 in avv.css in comparison to where your media query is?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to use !important next to the value.
Like so:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .content-wrapper > .content {
        padding: 0 0 !important;
    }

    .container, .container-fluid, .container-xl, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm {
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 0 !important;
        padding-left: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

If you dont't want to use !important you need to also define values for bigger screen. Exemple:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 577px) {
    .content-wrapper > .content {
        padding: 10px 10px /*Or Whatever value you need*/;
    }

    .container, .container-fluid, .container-xl, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm {
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 10px 10px /*Or Whatever value you need*/;
        padding-left: 10px 10px /*Or Whatever value you need*/;
    }
}
```